# How do I use Django South when my app is inside another directory?

Tags: python, mysql, django, migration, django-south

So by default, Django creates apps inside the root project dir. But I moved it inside "apps".

```
py manage.py  schemamigration ./apps/chat --initial
```

This doesn't work.

Instead of "chat", I put "chat" Inside another directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is apps python module or just directory?

if apps python modue, 
add apps.chat to installed apps in settings.py

and run

```
py manage.py  schemamigration chat --initial
```

if apps is just directory, so you need to add this directory to your PYTHONPATH.
add these lines at near top of your manage.py

```
import os
import sys
SITE_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
APPS_ROOT = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'apps')
sys.path.append(APPS_ROOT)
```

add chat to your settings.

now run

```
py manage.py  schemamigration chat --initial
```

and don't forget to add south to installed apps for both.