# Add a subdirectory of another project as a subtree

Tags: python, django, git

I have a git project (a Django app) and I want to add another app (https://github.com/lambdafu/django-south) as a subtree. The problem is that the third-party repository has an extra directory layer at its root. I don't want to have to mess with python's load path, add symlinks, or extra prefixes to import statements. Is there a way to get the `south` subdirectory as a subtree in my project?

Comment: OHHHHHH -- Today I Learned about [git-subtree](https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree).

Comment: Are you trying to include South as a dependency for your project?

Comment: That repo has a setup.py- unless you have a good reason to actually need the source, you should be installing the repo and updating whenever you want the new HEAD.

Comment: I'm actually looking for the answer of how you add a repo's subdirectory as a subtree. Anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

Let's call the root directory of the south project `repo`.

You could make `repo` a python module by adding an `__init__.py`, and then add `repo.south` to installed apps.

(borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5785207/931277))

You can also add `repo` as a [git submodule](http://book.git-scm.com/5_submodules.html) so you can maintain specific revisions of south along with specific revisions of your project.

Comment: Right, this is the "Add extra prefixes to import statements" option I didn't want to do. It also means maintaining a `__init__.py` file in the subdirectory. If I go the subtree route that probably won't cause merge conflicts, but I don't know a convenient way to maintain it if I use a submodule.

Comment: Ah right.  So the only solution for you is to avoid changing the directory structure at all.  As far as I know, there's no way to clone less than the entire git repo.  My guess is a symlink will end up being easiest.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to include South as a dependency? Because that's what it sounds like. If so, there's a better way than including the directory in your project's tree. That's messy and we have tools for that.

Do you use [pip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip)? How about [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv)? If so, `pip install -e git+https://github.com/lambdafu/django-south#egg=south` and you'll be good to go. To update to the latest HEAD after install, you'd just add the `-U` flag. You can even keep your requirements in a req file (`pip freeze > requirements.txt`, `pip install -r requirements.txt`) to keep them in version control.

If not, why not?

Comment: I normally use pip, but in this case I am deploying to a server with a paranoid sysadmin who doesn't allow outgoing connections or adding system-wide python packages. The idea was to have all my dependencies in the source tree so a git push over ssh is all that is needed. Sort of the way nodejs does modules. Maybe I can workaround it by asking him to install pip and use its bundle feature.

Comment: You can simply copy the environment from your existing virtualenv (tar+zip) and then expand it on the server. No external connections required.

Comment: Exactly. And that means no system-wide package installs, either. All you'd need is virtualenv installed in user-space for whatever user is running your Python app.